# UITableView reloadSections before reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a standard UIViewController with a UITableView inside of it.  I am trying to reloadSections; however, it is locking up my app.  I've noticed that the very first time that I load data in the table and I call reloadSections, it locks up; however, if I call reloadData the FIRST time, and reloadSections after subsequent updates it works fine.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: If you only do reloadData, it should pick up new sections as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you mean,but you can try this.

```
[CATransaction begin];  
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{  
     [yourTable reloadData];  
}];  
[yourTable reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Hope this helps you.